# Как избавиться от вложенности при переборе списков

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Есть 10 списков, вида:

```
a1 = ['1','2','4']
a2 = ['a','b','d']
..
a10 = ['asd','add','fdd']
```

Как получить строки из этих списков, избегая вложенности?

```
out = []
for i in a1:
    for k in a2:
..
       for l in a10:
           res = f'{a1}__{a2} ..... {a10}'
           out.append(res)
```

Comment: Пример желаемого результата, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

используйте `itertools.product`

```
import itertools

for el in itertools.product(a1, a2, ..., a10):
    print("__".join(el))
```